Dynamics 365 Sales OnPost event executed twice
I encountered an issue while testing a code that opens a related entity's form in a new tab upon saving under specific conditions in Dynamics. The issue is that the postsave event is executed twice on a specific terminal, causing two forms to open.
This behavior occurs frequently when transitioning stages in the business process flow and happens on the development terminal using Edge. The exact conditions for this issue are unclear as it does not always occur with the same operations.
I have tried restarting the PC and clearing the cache and history, but neither resolved the issue. This problem does not occur on other terminals and does not happen in Chrome.
While monitoring with the developer tools, I noticed that the onsave event is executed only once, but the onpostsave event is executed twice. Could there be a script left somewhere in Edge?
If anyone has any insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your help.
